# How to implement a Timer widget where minutes and seconds are vertically displayed

Tags: flutter, timer, flutter-animation, clock, mobile-development

[image]

I want to achive the above style in flutter.

What I have implemented so far:
[image]

Why is there unnecessary space between the texts.

I have done some debugging:
[image]

How can. I remove the vertical padding from the both texts.

My Code:

```
return SizedBox(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      child: CircleProgressBar(
        foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
        value: 0.0,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                "30",
                style: clockStyle,
              ),
              Align(
                child: Text(
                  "26",
                  style: clockStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Clock Style:

```
TextStyle clockStyle = GoogleFonts.alfaSlabOne(
  fontSize: 100,
);
```

Comment: add circular progress bar code aswell.
As far I can see from your code, the space is because you have a sized box of a given height. so both the widgets take equal space. That is why you see the unwanted space.

Comment: the circular progess bar is 3rd party package from pub.dev. The widget takes a child so I gave it a column with two texts. I have not added any sized box anywhere.

Comment: Please include the definition for `clockStyle`.

Comment: @jmatth added it.

Answer (score 0):

The rendered text is adding extra vertical space based on its size, known as [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading). Set the font height to `1` to remove it:

```dart
TextStyle clockStyle = GoogleFonts.alfaSlabOne(
  fontSize: 100,
  height: 1,
);
```

Comment: There's also likely some space for ascenders and descenders.  Type is tricky. :)